# chkrootkit config file options

Tags: configuration

I have installed the `chkrootkit` package with `sudo apt-get install chkrootkit`. When going to the `/etc/chkrootkit.conf` config file I see the following options:

```
RUN_DAILY="false"
RUN_DAILY_OPTS="-q"
DIFF_MODE="false"
```

I assume that the `RUN_DAILY` option if enabled would get `chkrootkit` to run an automated scan daily, and that the `RUN_DAILY_OPTS` sets what kind of scan the daily scan is in terms of which option it is using. Am I correct here? And if so then these automated scans, where are the results logged and how often do these scans occur?

Also, what does the `DIFF_MODE` option do? And should I enable it?

I have read the README file [here](http://www.chkrootkit.org/README) and found nothing to do with this config file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RUN_DAILY
```

If "yes" it runs daily automatically, it "no" you need to run it manually. Als have a look at `/etc/cron.daily/chkrootkit`. Here you can add something like it sending the report to an e-mail address.

```
RUN_DAILY_OPTS
```

These are options you can include. -q means quiet so it does not print anything on screen when running.

```
DIFF_MODE
```

If this is set to "yes" chrootkit compares the files `/var/log/chkrootkit/log.expected` with `/var/log/chkrootkit/log.today`.

---

Have a look at `/etc/cron.daily/chkrootkit` and `$CHKROOTKIT $RUN_DAILY_OPTS`. You can expand this with a `| mail -s $HOSTNAME $YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS` (untested!) to have it send mails after the scan is done.

Answer (score 0):

Had to google around to get all this info...

edit /etc/cron.daily/chkrootkit

```
#        eval $CHKROOTKIT $RUN_DAILY_OPTS | (egrep -v -f "${IGNORE_FILE}" || true)
$CHKROOTKIT > $LOG_DIR/chkrootkit.log #Run chkrootkit and save the logfile
(
echo "Subject: [chkrootkit] $(hostname -f) - Daily report" #Create subject line using the hostname
echo "To: $REPORT_EMAIL" #Insert To: delivery email address using the variable defined in chkrootkit.conf
echo ""
cat $LOG_DIR/chkrootkit.log #Concat the logfile to the output
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $REPORT_EMAIL #Send out the email!
```

edit /etc/chkrootkit.conf

```
RUN_DAILY="true"
RUN_DAILY_OPTS="-q"
DIFF_MODE="false"
REPORT_EMAIL="your-email-address@your-domain.co"
```

edit/create /etc/logrotate.d/chkroot

```
/var/log/chkrootkit/*.log {
  daily
  rotate 15
  dateext
  delaycompress
  missingok
  notifempty
}
```

run chkrootkit to generate a baseline

/etc/cron.daily/chkrootkit

Copy the existing log to the log expected file

cp /var/log/chkrootkit/chkrootkit.log /var/log/chkrootkit/log.expected

Should be good to go.